# How to create an intersection function?

Tags: python

I am making a 1 dimensional interval where I have to check if self intersects another object.

Here is what i have so far:

```
def __init__(self, lbound, rbound):
    """
    Constructs a new interval given its lower and upper bounds.
    """

    self._lbound = lbound
    self._rbound = rbound
```

And this is my function:

```
def intersects(self, other):
    """
    Returns True if self intersects other and False othewise.
    """

    s1 = set([self._lbound, self._rbound])
    s2 = set([other._lbound, other._rbound])
    if s1.intersection(s2) and s2.intersection(s1):
        return True
```

The problem is this function only gives half the answer I want, whats a 
better way to check if self intersects other?

Comment: Your sets only contains two elements each, not a range of numbers

Comment: How do you define "intersect"? Overlap? One completely inside the other?

Comment: Are the two ends of your intervals opened or closed?

Comment: Overlap I think

Comment: I would use less than / greater than. You have four numbers to check. Draw a picture of your true conditions, then write the code

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this instead:

```
def intersects(self, other):
    return (other._lbound < self._lbound < other._rbound or
            other._lbound < self._rbound < other._rbound or
            self._lbound < other._lbound < self._rbound or
            self._lbound < other._rbound < self._rbound)
```

Comment: The first two (or the last two) inequalities are enough - if one of `self`s ends lies inside `other` then one of `other`s ends is guaranteed to lie within `self` too.

Comment: @GregNavis the last two checks are to see if one range is completely inside of the other one.

Comment: Good point, Francisco! Using inequalities is deceptively simple and I got fixated on simplifying your code. Also, I noticed that your code doesn't work when `self` is the same as `other`, i.e. it says that an interval doesn't intersect itself which is obviously false. I posted an alternative approach in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly implement this predicate with inequalities. The downside of this approach is poor readability and a high likelihood of making a mistake. I recommend you break this problem down into two subproblems:

1. Intersecting two intervals.
2. Checking whether an interval is empty.

I assume that you're using **open** intervals. If not, please adjust the code accordingly.

## Constructing the code

First, let's have a class for representing intervals:

```
class Interval(object):
    def __init__(self, lhs, rhs):
        self.lhs = lhs
        self.rhs = rhs
```

An empty interval will be represented as one with `lhs >= rhs` (which also makes sense from the mathematical point of view). Let's add a predicate that checks whether an interval is empty:

```
    def is_empty(self):
        return self.lhs >= self.rhs
```

Let's turn our attention to intersections. An intersection of two intervals is an interval (possibly empty). The left and right endpoints can be computed with `min` and `max` like this:

```
    def intersect(self, other):
        return Interval(max([self.lhs, other.lhs]), min([self.rhs, other.rhs]))
```

As a last step, let's add `__repr__` so that we'll be able to `print` the interval and see its endpoints:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Interval(%r, %r)' % (self.lhs, self.rhs)
```

## Checking for non-empty intersections

The operation you're trying to perform can be expressed as:

```
a.intersect(b).is_empty()
```

where `a` and `b` are two `Interval`s.

## Full source

I'm including the full source for your convenience.

```
class Interval(object):
    def __init__(self, lhs, rhs):
        self.lhs = lhs
        self.rhs = rhs

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.lhs >= self.rhs

    def intersect(self, other):
        return Interval(max([self.lhs, other.lhs]), min([self.rhs, other.rhs]))

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Interval(%r, %r)' % (self.lhs, self.rhs)
```